# onSharedPreferenceChanged taking very long or not being called at all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-preferences

It seems that no matter what I do, my code to update my edit text summaries will not work unless I wait 20 seconds first. Sometimes it won't even be called then. However, when I go to another activity and return to the fragment within the activity it will be changed immediately. It's very weird.

I've cut out all the useless piece of code below:

```
public class Settings extends Activity { //Parent Activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();        
}

@Override //Method that does the changing
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) {
getActivity().onContentChanged(); //even tried adding this guy to not avail

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
//the method ends with that line
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to include  your:

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1)

In your first onCreate ??